# Getting the second lowest value in an array using only loops while already having the lowest value

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to figure out on how to get the second lowest value from an array that is input by the user.

To get the lowest value I've done this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if( array[i] < min ) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
```

To get the second lowest value I have tried this

```
int secMin = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
        if(array[i+1] > array[i]) {
            secMin = array[i];
        }
    }
```

The output is not consistent, meaning sometimes its right sometimes it isn't.I've tried changing the loop as well as the statements but its just guess work and I'm not making any real progress. Any tips?

Comment: You could simply update your first loop to look for both min and secMin at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply update your first loop to look for both min and secMin at the same time. Try this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int secmin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if( array[i] < min ) {
            secmin = min; // the min is now second min
            min = array[i]; // the curent value becomes min                
        } else if ( array[i] < secmin ){
            // if the value is greater than min but still less than second min then...
            secmin = array[i];
        } 
    }
```

I haven't tested it but something along those lines should work

There's another approach [described here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-find-second-smallest-number-in-an-array).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keeping doing it as 2 separate loops, just do the same as for the `min` value, but skip the `min` value when looking.

```java
// Find lowest value
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int value : array) {
    if (value < min) {
        min = value;
    }
}
```

```java
// Find second-lowest value
int secMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int value : array) {
    if (value != min) { // Skip/ignore lowest value
        if (value < secMin) {
            secMin = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can of course combine that:

```java
// Find second-lowest value
int secMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int value : array)
    if (value != min && value < secMin)
        secMin = value;
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!